# Notification not showing up at correct date

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm trying to create a reminder app that creates notifications for the user at a later/specific date.  I'm using an `AlarmManager` with a `PendingIntent` in order to achieve this.  The problem I keep getting is that when I try to specify the date to fire for `AlarmManager`, it doesn't fire at the scheduled date.  I tried putting in a regular value, such as 8000, and the notification fires immediately.  However, when I try adding the value as a date, the `BroadcaseReceiver` doesn't receive the `Intent`.  Below is my code.

```
    public void setReminderNotification (Context context) {

    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);


    notificationReceiverIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    notificationReceiverIntent.putExtra("Title", itemName);
    notificationReceiverIntent.putExtra("DueDate", dueDateString);


    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.clear();
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 6);
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 13);

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 48);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);



    notificationReceiverPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, var, notificationReceiverIntent, 0);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, notificationReceiverPendingIntent);

}
```

So the main problem is seems to be this line.

`alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, notificationReceiverPendingIntent);`

I expect the notification to fire off immediately since the target date is set to the past.  However, the notification doesn't appear immediately.  When I replace the `calendar.getTimeinMillis()` variable with something like 8000, the notification does appear immediately.  Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

Note in [AlarmManager documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html):

> Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS
>   will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There
>   are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery
>   guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and
>   setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose
>   targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the
>   previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when
>   requested.

In your case, you should call `setExact()`.

Comment: I was using `setRepeating()` since I wanted to make an alarm that would signal from a start date, and repeat on a daily basis until an end date.  If I use `setWindow` or `setExact`, this wouldn't be possible.  In my case, would I have to create a new `PendingIntent` for each day to signal a unique notification?

Comment: @victorydub Your suggestion is imho the best solution. You need to create an alarm for the next day when you are processing the actual day. Do not forget to handle state, when device is restarted, because all alarms all turned off. You have to catch broadcast message `BOOT_COMPLETED` and create an alarm again.